# Authentication in Laravel using 2 tables

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a connection system using 2 tables with Laravel in fact  my tables are like this

### Users

Id
Username
Id_agence

### Agences

Id
Code 
password

I use the foreign Key id_agence in users table

Answer (score 3):

```
$user=DB::table("Users")
                        ->join("Agences",'Users.Id_agence','Agences.id')
                        ->where("Users.Username","The username")
                        ->select("Agences.password as password")
                        ->first();
if(Hash::check("Your plain password",$user->password)){
----
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution rather than just adding code

Answer (score 0):

```
if(User::where('username', $request->username)->exists())
{
     $user = DB::table('users')
                       ->leftJoin('agences', 'users.id_agence', '=', 'agences.id')
                      ->where('users.username', $request->username)
                      ->first();

     $auth = Hash::check($request->password, $user->password);

         if($user && $auth)
         {
              Auth::login($user);

              Session::flash('success', 'LogIn Successful!');
              return redirect()->intended(route('user.index'));
         } 
     else
         { 
             //If unsuccessful then redirect back
             Session::flash('error', 'Email or password is incorrect!');

             return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 
             'remember'));
         } 
 }
```

> 1. Check if the username requested via the form or any other method exists in the users database or not.
> 2. If true join the "agences" table with the user table to fetch all the information along with the stored hashed password.
> 3. Use the Hash::check method which allows to verify a given plain text corresponding to given hash.
> 4. Check if both conditions are true then you authenticate a user via Auth::login and redirect it to intended route else redirect back.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @xiawi I did so accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function traitement()
    {
        request()->validate([
            'username' =>  ['required'],
            'pass' => ['required']
        ]);



        $result = auth()->attempt([
            'username' => request('username'),
            'password' => request('pass'),
        ]);

        if($result){  
            flash("Your now connected")->success();

            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return back()->withInput()->withErrors([
            'pass' => 'Incorrect identifier'
        ]);
    }
```

here is what I have try first